# Jquery Ajax help point in right direction

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Hi I am using a third party plugin.  That if I pass it a url manually it returns a value as expected, when I use AJAX in Jquery it returns nothing, I have no idea how to debug this or how to attempt to sort, any help much appreciated.

The url that works

```
    http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=C5
```

The Jquery code that doesn't

```
      $.ajax({type: 'Get', url: 'http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx',
        data: {t: 'ab', f: 'DeviceStatus', d: 'C5'},
        success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
                  },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);

          }
          });
```

Comment: Does your aspx page output something that you can check? A quick test is to make your aspx page ONLY output a simple string like "Here I am" (in fact, delete everything else in the aspx file for this test -- you can undelete it again in 2 minutes) and see if that string is alerted in your $.ajax success function. At least you'll know that much is working.

Comment: Be sure to check your console during AJAX calls, it provides extremely important info, such as if the request has went thru to the server or been stopped.

Comment: It's not my ASPX page, entering the URL manually does return an answer ok.

Comment: Sorry to ask a silly question how do I check my console?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

```
return Json(dataset, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//(C# MVC)
```

...
//Not your aspx page// try changing your get to a post to see if responds differently.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up your page that runs this code in Chrome, hit f12 to bring up chrome tools.
2. Click "Sources"
3. Set a break point on the lines your'd like to break on, I'd suggest where you put those "alerts()".  You set a breakpoint by clicking the number for the line number in the Sources tab.  You'll see a little blue icon where the break point is.
4. After you do the ajax request and break inspect your request and status objects.  Check out the responseText, status and also poke around the other fields and see what you find.

Another Thing you can do:
Download http://fiddler2.com/

This is an HTTP debugging tool that is a critical tool for any dev.

HTH.

Comment: I cant find  the request and status objects.